# XPATH:How to select node in a different level?

Tags: xml, xpath, selection

What I want to do through XPATH is to retrieve the coordinates of placemark with name Poly 1. Probably a very simple question but my knowledge of XPATH is limited and I struggle with the fact that there is an extra tag present between name and coordinates("polygon")

As you can see there can be one or more  elements and I would like to retrieve them all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
<Document>
       <Placemark>
            <name>Poly 1</name>
            <Polygon>
                        <coordinates>
                            -58.40844625779582,-34.60295278618136,0
                        </coordinates>
                        <coordinates>
                            -68.40844625779582,-77.60295278618136,0
                        </coordinates>

            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Poly 2</name>
            <Polygon>
                        <coordinates>
                            -58.40414334150432,-34.59992445476809,0
                        </coordinates>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPATH expression will get your the coordinates nodes

```
//Placemark[./name[text()='Poly 1']]//coordinates
```

This is how it works:

- `//Placemark` selects all Placemark tags
- `//Placemark[./name]` selects all Placemark tags with a name child tag
- `//Placemark[./name[text()='Poly 1']]` selects all Placemark tags with a name child tag, where the name tag contains the text `Poly 1`.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I got it working on my xml document as well :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept answers that answers your questions.